# Intersection of lists of disjoint intervals

Tags: intersection, intervals

Here is my problem: I have two very large lists of intervals (stored as many couples in the form `{{"start point", "end point"}, ..., {"start point", "end point"}`), and I want the result of the intersection of those lists.

Here is an example :

```
intervalsA = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 7}, {8, 8.5}};
intervalsB = {{1.5, 3.5}, {4.1, 6}, {9, 10}};
```

The expected result is: `overlap = {{1.5, 2}, {3, 3.5}, {5, 6}};`

I tried using `Interval`, `IntervalUnion` and `IntervalIntersection`, but nothing worked. The only working method that I found uses `Piecewise` functions where each interval is set as 1. By multiplying the two piecewise functions, I have something similar to the intersection, but the solution is very inefficient.

I hope I am clear and precise enough.

Comment: Do you want the intersections of *each* of the intervals in the first list with *each* of the intervals in the second list? (Presumably you do *not* want intersections of corresponding entries in each of the two lists, since in the example your lists have different lengths.)

Comment: M can represent and operate on interval sets: `List @@ IntervalIntersection[Interval @@ intervalsA, 
  Interval @@ intervalsB]` --> `{{1.5, 2}, {3, 3.5}, {5, 6}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works really well with the required speed ! :) I feel kind of stupid because I didn't use those intervals properly.

Comment: @alancalvitti Excellent - Why don't you put this as an answer?

Comment: Related: my own (old) question from Stack Overflow: [(5784046)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5784046)

Comment: Can I set a comment as an answer ?

Comment: Mammouth: that depends on what you mean.  If you mean is it possible to Accept a comment as an answer, no.  If you mean is it possible to "promote" a comment to an answer, no.  However, you can always ask the author to post his comment as an answer, or you can even post it as an answer yourself, though it's polite to ask him first.  In this case it seems that @alancalvitti preferred merely to comment, and mfvonh has already (re)posted his method as an answer which you have Accepted.  Everything is as it should be. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for the reply, I'm quite new here (a few minutes I guess) even though Stackexchange happend to be very helpful more than once !

Comment: Oh oops I didn't notice the comment by @alancalvitti. Didn't mean to steal anyone's thunder.

Comment: @Mammouth Welcome aboard. :-)  Take a minute to view the [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).  If you have any questions about the site itself visit [Meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @mfvonh I think if he had wanted to Answer he would have.  It is good that you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
intervalsA = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 7}, {8, 8.5}};
intervalsB = {{1.5, 3.5}, {4.1, 6}, {9, 10}};
IntervalIntersection @@ Interval @@@ {intervalsA, intervalsB}
```

> Interval[{1.5, 2}, {3, 3.5}, {5, 6}]

Comment: A bit classier, but slightly less efficient than `List @@ IntervalIntersection[Interval @@ intervalsA,    Interval @@ intervalsB]`.

Comment: @Mammouth I don't see any difference in performance, and I think there shouldn't be as they are essentially equivalent. By the way the parentheses are extraneous here.

Answer (score 0):

or more general:

```
youFunction[intervals__] := Composition[
    DeleteCases[#, Interval[]] &,
    DeleteDuplicates,
    (IntervalIntersection @@ # &) /@ # &,
    Subsets[#, {2}] &,
    Join[##] &
    ][intervals];

intervalsA = Interval /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 7}, {8, 8.5}};
intervalsB = Interval /@ {{1.5, 3.5}, {4.1, 6}, {9, 10}};
youFunction[intervalsA, intervalsB]
(*{Interval[{1.5, 2}], Interval[{3, 3.5}], Interval[{5, 6}]}*)
```